# Selenium 2.0 WebDriver Advcanced Interactions DoubleClick Help (c#)

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, webdriver, double-click

So within my selenium regression tests, I've been trying to double click on a calendar to make a new appt. I have attempted to use the doubleClick(); method within the advanceduserinteractions library, but there is an issue; the two clicks aren't fast enough/close enough together to fire an actual double-click! Has anybody found a way to deal with this in their testing?

Comment: also, the calendar I'm using functions such as this one:
[link](http://google.latest.gwt-web-calendar.appspot.com)

Comment: Unfortunately the link doesn't allow to double click on an empty calendar to create a new appointment. However I was able to double click on an existing calendar and open it successfully. I used Actions API albeit in Java. Not sure if that's something you are looking for. I can post the code if you are interested

Comment: You're right, but even to simulate the double click on an already registered even does not work for my actual application. I am interested in the code though, as it may help me figure out the c# equivelent.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This code works for me!

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.doubleClick(myElemment);
action.perform();
```

Comment: I have tried that, but the Actions doubleClick() method doesn't fire both clicks fast enough to register as a double click for some reason..

Comment: Well, I updated to the current build of Selenium, and (with no code changes) it fires fast enough now haha. I'll mark this as the solution though, as I think the Actions driver is the simplest/most effective way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Java equivalent. This code will blindly open the first event. You could add some logic to open a specific event etc. This code works! (tested with 2.12)

```
List<WebElement> events = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.dv-appointment"));
for(WebElement event:events){
    WebElement body = event.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.body"));            
    if(!body.getText().isEmpty()) //or open a known event
    {
        System.out.println(body.getText()); //open the first event
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        Action doubleClick = builder.doubleClick(event)
                                    .build();
        doubleClick.perform();
        break;                  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not forget "using"

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Internal;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

//create Actions object
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
//create a chain of actions 
builder.DoubleClick().Build().Perform();
```

http://selenium-interview-questions.blogspot.ru/2014/03/how-to-double-click-on-web-element.html

Answer (score 1):

I too had the problem where Selenium's doubleclick event works in Firefox but has no effect in Chrome. Upgrading to Selenium didn't help; I already have the latest version. (My environment is Ubuntu 14.04, Python 2.7.6, Selenium 2.44.0, Firefox 35.0, Chrome 40.0.2214.91.)

I'm not sure why CBRRacer's answer was downvoted. I successfully worked around the problem by using two click events. This works in both Firefox and Chrome. There are two ways do to it, and both worked for me.

The first way:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#myElement')
elem.click()
elem.click()
```

The second way:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#myElement')
actions = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(elem).click(elem).perform()
```

Answer (score 1):

I quite like the approach used here, particularly queuing the actions first, then performing, since that allows repeated application of the actionchain.

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains

From the documentation example linked:

```
menu = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".nav")
hidden_submenu = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".nav #submenu1")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(menu)
actions.click(hidden_submenu)
actions.perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried catching the IWebElement and then clicking it twice?

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("yourID"));
element.Click();
element.Click();
```

I don't know if this would give you the desird functionality or not but I know that when I execute a click event like the one above it runs as close as a double click from an actual user.

The other option is to reference the `ThoughtWorks.Selenium.Core`, however the only downside of this is that I'm not sure it plays well with the current `IWebDriver` I think it needs it's own instantiation of the `IWebDriver`.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work. I tried this before the AdvancedUserInteractions, but neither seem to actually perform a Double Click.