# Selenium: Select row in table

Tags: c#, selenium

Maybe you could help me. I need to double click specific row depending on if row's column has value i.e. "something". All rows has same classname. This code need also to stop with first 
row which has specific value and doubleclick it.

Sorry i can't give any code because i dont have anything to show (a lot of tries and mistakes).

I hope you can help me. I don't have any ideas how to do this.

```
<tr class="a">
   <td>Title</td>
   <td>Anything</td>
</tr>
<tr class="a">
   <td>Title</td>
   <td>something</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Title</td>
   <td>Anything</td>
</tr>
<tr class="a">
   <td>Title</td>
   <td>something</td>
</tr>
```

if you could give me example in c# i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend xpath or css, so the selector for the element would be in xpath: `//td[text()='something']` or maybe `td[contains(text(),'something')]` and for css it is `css=td:contains('something')`. Personally I prefer xpath.

And the 'findElement()'-Methode always takes the first suitable Element.

I never used selenium in c#, but I can give you an example in Java, if you Need it.

This will doubleclick the first td-Element () with the text 'something':

```
//find Element
WebElement tdElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()='something']"));

//doubleclick
tdElement.click();
tdElement.click();

//wait for expected action to happen
...doSomething();
```

If you have further questions, please let me know.

Comment: if you could it would be nice

Comment: If you have trouble with the doubleclick, then please consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387362/selenium-2-0-webdriver-advcanced-interactions-doubleclick-help-c