# Unable to doubleclick in selenium webdriver c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, action, double-click

I'm trying to doubleclick on an option within a selectbox using the Actions class in c# Selenium WebDriver. The following code works fine for firefox but not for IE or Chrome. Any suggestions on why or how I might investigate whats going wrong?

```
var sideBarAgentList = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#agentSelectBox")));
var agentInList = sideBarAgentList.Options.First(o => o.Text == "Agent49159 - 49159");
new Actions(driver).DoubleClick(agentInList).Perform();
```

The HTML is

```
<select id="agentSelectBox" ondblclick="javascript:addAgentDesktop(this.selectedIndex);" onchange="javascript:showAgentInfo(this.selectedIndex);" style="width:220px;background:#e0e0e0;font-family:Verdana;font-size:75%;" size="22">

  <option value="0" style="background:white;color:blue">

      Agent49159 - 49159

  </option>

</select>
```

Comment: Have you made sure this is not a wait issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I can tell the doubleclick action does not work in IE or Chrome on an option in a select element. I have updated my code to click the option from the select menu, then doubleclick the select element itself rather than the option. Works for FF, IE and Chrome.

```
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#agentSelectBox"))).Options.First(o => o.Text == "Agent49159 - 49159").Click();;       
new Actions(driver).DoubleClick(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#agentSelectBox"))).Perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this row: `new Actions(driver).DoubleClick(agentInList).Perform();`

**to:** `new Actions(driver).DoubleClick(agentInList).build().Perform();`

Comment: HI, that didn't appear to have any effect. The doubleclick continued to work in FF but not Chrome or IE. I have now found a solution that works for all 3 so will post

Comment: Did you add Chrome and IE driver to your project ?!

Answer (score 0):

Like user3198015, I have found that Selenium's doubleclick action works in Firefox but not Chrome. A workaround is to use two click events, as shown in my answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387362/selenium-2-0-webdriver-advcanced-interactions-doubleclick-help-c/28112524#28112524).