# Loop behaving like nested loops when iterating through ReadOnlyCollection<AppiumWebElement>

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, automation, appium-desktop

I encountered an issue while trying to check all the checkboxes in a windows application

This is my code:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

var elements = driver.FindElementByName("Upload Categories").FindElementsByTagName("CheckBox");
        
foreach (var element in elements)
{
    actions.DoubleClick(element).Perform();
}
```

And I would expect the code to iterate through all the elements and double click on them.

Instead it behaves like there is another loop inside iterating a list of elements made out of the required element and all the elements indexed before it in the initial list.

I don't understand why

**SOLVED:**

It had something to do with the fact that "actions" is declared outside of the loop

**This is the working version:**

```
var elements = driver.FindElementByName("Upload Categories").FindElementsByTagName("CheckBox");
        
foreach (var element in elements)
{
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.DoubleClick(element).Perform();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean " behaves like there is another loop inside"? What is the behavior?

Comment: If it was an array of integers, lets say 1 to 5 a Console.WriteLine(element) in the loop would generate the following output: "1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5"

Comment: Ok, but it's not integers, so what is the behavior you ARE seeing.

Comment: I have a list of checkboxes that need to be checked, it is checking the first one with the first iteration, on the second iteration it's unchecking the first box and checking the second and so on.

Comment: what browser are you using? DoubleClick has some issues across browsers https://stackoverflow.com/a/26295142/1387701

Comment: It's not a browser, it's a windows app and it does the same thing if I use " element.Click() " twice

Comment: You're using selenium but not a browser??